# Load bitmap from resource file to image

Tags: image, delphi, resources, bitmap, load

how do I load an image bmp from resource file and load it into image1.Picture? I tried this:

```
{$R resource.res}
procedure TForm1.Image1MouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
var
 BitMap1 : TBitMap;
begin
  BitMap1 := TBitMap.Create;
  try
    BitMap1.LoadFromResourceName(HInstance,'down');
    Image1.Picture(BitMap1);
  finally
    BitMap1.Free;
  end;
end;
```

but does't work. Thanks!

---

I created a file. rc:

```
DOWN BMP DOWN.BMP
```

and I compiled with brcc32.exe:

```
brcc32.exe resource.rc
```

I implemented the resource:

```
{$R resource.res}
```

but can not find the file bmp.

---

It does not work, always an error, however I found another code:

```
procedure TForm1.Image1MouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
begin
   Image1.Picture.Bitmap.Handle := LoadBitmap(hInstance, 'DOWN');
end;
```

But when I click on the image disappears, why? Thanks

This is the code:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls, XPMan, ExtCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    XPManifest1: TXPManifest;
    Image1: TImage;
    procedure Image1MouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
      Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}
{$R RESOURCE.RES}

procedure TForm1.Image1MouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
begin
   Image1.Picture.Bitmap.Handle := LoadBitmap(hInstance,'DOWN');
end;

end.
```

Comment: What doesn't work? Are you getting error messages? Does nothing appear?

Comment: One thing I see wrong right away is `Image1.Picture(BitMap1);` - Shouldn't this be `Image1.Picture.Assign(BitMap1);`?

Comment: I tried: Image1.Picture.Assign(BitMap1); but i get an error: Resource down not found.

Comment: Then all I can say is make sure you have placed the resource here.

Comment: The resource is placed correctly

Comment: @Jerry, he did. `{$R resource.res}`.

Comment: @Giacomo - Please verify the resource is actually in the executable (in a bitmap section) by a third party resource viewer/compiler..

Comment: A quick and dirty way to check is compile with what *should* include the image, check the file size, then compile again without it, and compare the file sizes.

Comment: You are aware your .rc file is wrong, aren't you (BITMAP <> BMP)?

Comment: If I put BITMAP instead of BMP, the compiler gives me an error: INVALID BITMAP FORMAT, so I have to put BMP.

Comment: @Giacomo - `LoadBitmap`, `LoadImage` with IMAGE_BITMAP, `FindResource` with RT_BITMAP, these will all look for a **BITMAP** resource. If you don't put it in a 'bitmap' section, you can't use `LoadFromResourceName` of `TBitmap`. Believe me!

Comment: I solved it by converting the bmp file to color-scale. Thanks to all.

Answer (score 7):

You have to create the resource correctly in the first place. Example (generic Delphi, since you didn't specify a version) below.

File: `Resource.rc` (terrible name, BTW, and a terrible resource name)

```
DOWN BITMAP DOWN.BMP
```

Then include the file in the code for the compiler to process:

```
{$R resource.res resource.rc}

procedure TForm1.Image1MouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton; 
  Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
var
 BitMap1 : TBitMap;
begin
  BitMap1 := TBitMap.Create;
  try
    BitMap1.LoadFromResourceName(HInstance,'DOWN');
    Image1.Picture.Assign(Bitmap1);;
  finally
    BitMap1.Free;
  end;
end;
```

If your version of Delphi doesn't support the above `{$R }` directive, just remove the `resource.rc` part, and compile the resource from a command prompt in your project folder first:

```
brcc32 resource.rc
```

Comment: Hmm, I just tried `Bmp.LoadFromResourceName(HInstance, 'bbabort');` in a D2007 executable (they have a few bitmaps by default), and then draw the bitmap on the form canvas without a problem.

Comment: @Sertac, strange. I just had an issue a few weeks ago with a resource name seeming to be case-sensitive (using `SomeResource` failed, changing it to `SOMERESOURCE` worked, with no other changes). It used to be documented in the MSDN resource file format, but I haven't checked it in ages. I'll see if I can locate it, but even if it doesn't matter the above code correctly loads the resource while the original question's code did not. :-)

Comment: @Sertac, you're right. This restriction has changed (or is different somehow in Delphi); loading `bbabort` does in fact work now. I'll remove that sentence. Thanks for the correction. :-)

Answer (score 0):

In Delphi 10 or later you can to create the resource go up to ***Project Menu
Project > Resources and Images***

http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Resources_and_Images